# What is the difference between HD LED Glare and HD LED Backlit?

Tags: display

I was comparing this two products from [Lenovo](http://www.snapdeal.com/product/lenovo-essential-g5070-59413724-laptop/938891074#Technical%20Specifications) and [Dell](http://www.snapdeal.com/product/dell-inspiron-3542-notebook-4th/1840057484#Technical%20Specifications). There are no major differences but one difference in their display. Can anyone help me what is the difference between HD LED Glare and HD LED Backlit displays?

Answer (score 2):

"Glare" and "Backlit" are two different, unrelated things.

LED Backlit means the LCD is lit from behind using [LEDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode) as the light source. This will actually be true for both displays in question (since they are both "LED" LCD displays).

See this similar SU question: [Difference between a LED Backlit and LED HD Display on laptop monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/261042/difference-between-a-led-backlit-and-led-hd-display-on-laptop-monitor)

"Glare" means the screen is smooth/[glossy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossy_display) instead of having a [matte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matte_display) finish (matte screens are for "anti-glare").

For more info on Matte vs. Glossy, check out this other SU question:  [What makes glass monitors different from matte or glossy?](https://superuser.com/questions/30424/what-makes-glass-monitors-different-from-matte-or-glossy)